# Should I use "ones" here?

Tags: word-choice

As I try to find a word to refer to "interaction" here, I am afraid that people can mistake it with other plural nouns in the sentence.

> Interactions by email, phones or videos are as good as face-to-face **ones**.

Answer (score 2):

I would write this as:

> Interactions by email, phone, or video are as good as face-to-face ones.

"Ones" shyould agree with "Interactions". But "email, phone, or video" are the methods of interaction beign discussed, and the singular form is normally used when referring to such a medium in general. This also flows better and avoids confusion, in my view.

Comment: Alternatively, make everything singular and rephrase the end: *Interaction by email, phone, or video is as good as it is face to face.*